# NTLDR is corrupt the system cannot boot - Win 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, bios, iso

I have a new server with no OS.
I setup BIOS to boot from the DVD drive.

I opended the ISO file for Windows 2008 RS using PowerISO.
Then burned it to DVD.

I insert the DVD in and when I boot up I get error: NTLDR is corrupt the system cannot boot

Debugging steps:

I tried both Win 2008 Standard and Web editions.

I also tried renaming the files, like changing:
en_windows_web_server_2008_x64_dvd_x14-26683.iso
to:
26683.iso

I also tried burning it at a slower speed: 2x

Same error each time.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: What happens when you put the ISO in a working computer? You can open and browse the files without issue?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a corrupted ISO. There is no NTLDR in Win2008 and newer OSes. They use BCD and winload.exe. Try verifying the checksum of the ISO with the download source, probably don't match.

Comment: No, I downloaded it straight from MSDN. Could there be an issue how I burned it perhaps?

Comment: So the checksum does or does not match?

Answer (score 0):

If you opened the ISO and then burned the contents, you did it wrong. Doing that will cause you to lose the boot sector, among other things. You need to burn the ISO as a whole. Windows 7/2008R2 can do this natively. If you're on an older OS, there are tons of tools to do this.